# how to hash password in views for registering a user in custom user model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

this is my code snippet where i am registering a new user based on custom user model. i need to hash the password before storing user. having no idea how to do this. any help would be appreciated.

```
 class UserCreate(APIView):
        # User Creation->
        def post(self, request, format='json'):

            serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                user = serializer.save()
                if user:
                    token = Token.objects.create(user=user)
                    json = serializer.data
                    json['token'] = token.key
                    return Response(json, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
                return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

the problem is that it is creating user without hashing the password and when i am trying to log in with the credentials i am getting the issue

```
"non_field_errors": [ "Unable to log in with provided credentials." ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you can override your Serializer's [**`create()`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances) method:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password')
        user = User(**validated_data)
        user.set_password(password)
        return user
```

Comment: thanks, it worked, i just needed to save the user at last by `user.save()`

Comment: My password is in hashed, however it seems different from the superuser therefore it can't authenticate